# yii2 assets not loading

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

Yii2 $depends not loaded CSS and Js file.

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',      
];
```

Above code not load js and CSS file when page load.Please, anyone, help me to shoot this problem.

Getting following error

> GET http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/cb4e03a0/jquery.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> login:668 GET http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/e446c213/yii.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/e446c213/yii.validation.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/e446c213/yii.activeForm.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> GET http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/cb4e03a0/jquery.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> GET http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/e446c213/yii.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/e446c213/yii.validation.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED
>
> http://localhost/php/backend/web/assets/e446c213/yii.activeForm.js 404
>   (Not Found)

Comment: try removing the contents of the folder `backend/web/assets` and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was found the issue in bootstrap version. Do the following step to solve these problems.

1. Removed vendor folder from your project root directory
2. Composer update

Comment: Still same issue for me, nothing really changed. Could you please explain a little more on the answer to review other possible options?